# If mysql_num_rows equals to ZERO is NOT working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this code to count rows and trying to do `IF num rows equals to ZERO do INSERT if not UPDATE` but it doesn't work.

When I use `==` operator nothing happens. If I use `>=` operator script inserting the values but running insert query on every refresh and values are duplicating in MySQL table.

Here is the code:

```
$isexist = mysql_query("select count(*) from wcddl_filehosts where downloadid = '".$download[id]."'");

if (mysql_num_rows($isexist) == 0) {
mysql_query("insert into wcddl_filehosts (downloadid, rs) values ('".$download[id]."','$totalRS')");
} else {
mysql_query("update wcddl_filehosts set rs = '$totalRS' where downloadid = '".$download[id]."'");
}
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Retagged, as this has nothing to do with preg_match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Count will return a value, and you cannot count and then call mysql_num_rows.  It is either one of the other.

You could do

```
$isExist = mysql_query("Select count(id) from ..."); 
$r = mysql_fetch_array($isExist);
if($r['COUNT(id)'] > 0){
//item exists
}else{
//item doesnt exist
}
```

If alternatively you can do the query as:

```
$isexist = mysql_query("select * from wcddl_filehosts where downloadid = '".$download[id]."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($isExists)>0){
//we have items
}else{
//we dont have items
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. but i want to ask which way faster?

Comment: It is a matter of mysql returning the count itself versus php performing the count.  I would imagine MySQL is better at counting then php is however this is just a hunch, nothing more nothing less. :-) 
Although if you are talking about millions of records then MySQL will be faster I am almost positive.

Comment: The reason using MySQL to count is a better choice is because MySQL doesn't have to build and send back the entire result set (which in the case of millions of records is a LOT Of data) before a total is calculated.  The general rule of thumb when you're using SELECT from MySQL is never to return results you don't need, as it's a waste of I/O resources.

Comment: In your alternative solution the variables are not equal: $isexist <> $isExists. But when you change that it works fine.